# Como criar "bordas" de 90° na div

Tags: html, css

É possível criar bordas 90° na ponta das `div`'s pelo CSS? Segue exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `Before` e `After`

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
}
div:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
div:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
span:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
span:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```